# How to use Cyirllic alphabets in ruby rails in irb in ruby 2.1 version

Tags: puts

i am unable to enter cyrillic alphabets in ruby irb. I have installed cyrillizer,translit and try to paste cyrillic alphabets in irb but it doesnt allow me to paste into command prompt